# Updating list items through dynamically created button click event on page load. (Index was out of range)

Tags: c#, dynamic, webforms, pageload

Hi I am trying to dynamically create Buttons and TextBoxes from a List in my page load.
The Buttons have a click event attached which add one to the TextBox.
At the same time this happens I want to update the according List item to the new number.

My issue is that I am getting an error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

I don't seem to understand why I am getting the error and thus how I could fix my issue.
Below I prepared a code example that recreates the issue:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    List<ProductRates> ProductRateList = new List<ProductRates>() {
        new ProductRates(1,"Test",0),
        new ProductRates(2,"Test2",0),
        new ProductRates(3,"Test3",0)
    };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ProductRateList.Count; i++)
        {
            double testing = ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount;

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();                
            textBox.Text = "0";
            textBox.ID = ProductRateList[i].ProductName + "TextBox";

            Button plusButton = new Button();               
            plusButton.Text = "+";
            plusButton.ID = ProductRateList[i].ProductName + "PinusButton";
            plusButton.Click += (se, ev) => PlusButton_Click(se, ev, ProductRateList,i, textBox);                             

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createButtonDiv =
            new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createButtonDiv.ID = ProductRateList[i].ProductName + "createButtonDiv";
            createButtonDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-6");
            createButtonDiv.Controls.Add(plusButton);
            createButtonDiv.Controls.Add(textBox);              

            ProductPlaceholderDiv.Controls.Add(createButtonDiv);

        }

    }
    void PlusButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e, List<ProductRates> ProductRateList, int i, TextBox textBox)
    {
        string test = textBox.Text;
        ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount = 1 + double.Parse(test);
        textBox.Text = (ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount).ToString();
    }

    public class ProductRates
    {            
        public ProductRates(int prodductId, string productName , double productOrderAmount  )
        {
            ProdductId = prodductId;
            ProductName = productName;
            ProductOrderAmount = productOrderAmount;
        }
        //Product
        public int ProdductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }          
        public double ProductOrderAmount { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of "i" when PlusButton_Click(...) method is entered?

Comment: If i is id of element in collection, try something like collection.where(w=.w.Id==i) ....

Comment: @ThomasHahn I is 3, what is out of range of the List. Does this mean the PlusButton_Click event is fired after the Page_Load event?

Comment: Yes, the i is not saved for every buttons event, but the last value of i is used everytime the button click handler is invoked.

Comment: @ThomasHahn Is there a way that I can link these created buttons to the corresponding list item? The main goal is to update the ProductOrderAmount of i in the List item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use below new event handler =>

```
    private void PlusButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div =(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)btn.Parent;

        string ProductName = btn.ID.Substring(0, btn.ID.Length - "PinusButton".Length);

        TextBox txt = (TextBox)div.FindControl(ProductName + "TextBox");
        txt.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text)? "0":txt.Text) + 1).ToString();
    }
```

2) subscribe as =>

plusButton.Click += PlusButton_Click1;

Upvote if the solution works for you..thanks..enjoy coding

Comment: Thank you for your example.It is working but does not include the main goal. The main goal that I am trying to achieve is to update the ProductOrderAmount of i in the List item that is linked to that button.

Comment: Glad that the solution helped you move ahead in your goal. You can try adding the index information as a attribute on control Ex : plusButton.Attributes.Add("Index", i.ToString());   and then try accessing it in event handler as : ProductRateList[Convert.ToInt16(btn.Attributes["Index"])].ProductOrderAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txt.Text);    This will save you from looping unnecessary and will give you access to entire object as well

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem through help of @RiteshKulkarni answer.
Even though there is probably a better solution for this and if someone knows the answer please let me know.

Then on the click event that @RiteshKulkarni posted I added a loop that checks if the name is the corresponding one and use this to store the value in the list.

If someone knows a better way to achieve this please let me know.

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    List<ProductRates> ProductRateList = new List<ProductRates>() {
        new ProductRates(1,"Test",0),
        new ProductRates(2,"Test2",0),
        new ProductRates(3,"Test3",0)
    };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ProductRateList.Count; i++)
        {
            double testing = ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount;

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();                
            textBox.Text = ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount.ToString();
            textBox.ID = ProductRateList[i].ProductName + "TextBox";

            Button plusButton = new Button();               
            plusButton.Text = "+";
            plusButton.ID = ProductRateList[i].ProductName + "PinusButton";
            plusButton.Click += PlusButton_Click1;

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createButtonDiv =
            new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createButtonDiv.ID = ProductRateList[i].ProductName + "createButtonDiv";
            createButtonDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-6");
            createButtonDiv.Controls.Add(plusButton);
            createButtonDiv.Controls.Add(textBox);              

            ProductPlaceholderDiv.Controls.Add(createButtonDiv);

        }

    }
    private void PlusButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)btn.Parent;

        string ProductName = btn.ID.Substring(0, btn.ID.Length - "PinusButton".Length);

        TextBox txt = (TextBox)div.FindControl(ProductName + "TextBox");           
        for (int i = 0; i < ProductRateList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ProductRateList[i].TextBoxName == ProductName + "TextBox")
            {
                ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount = double.Parse(txt.Text) + 1;
                txt.Text = ProductRateList[i].ProductOrderAmount.ToString();
            }
        }

    }

    public class ProductRates
    {            
        public ProductRates(int prodductId, string productName , double productOrderAmount  )
        {
            ProdductId = prodductId;
            ProductName = productName;
            ProductOrderAmount = productOrderAmount;
        }
        //Product
        public int ProdductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }          
        public double ProductOrderAmount { get; set; }
        public string TextBoxName { get; set; }
    }
}
```